# Powershell Array Enumeration to Log

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am attempting to enumerate an array of certificates to a log file:

```
$allCerts = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | Select-Object name,subject,Thumbprint,Issuer,NotAfter
```

Then sending to log via logging function:

```
$allCerts | ForEach-Object {logger -logstr $_}
```

This shows the following in the log (sensitive info removed) - note the log isn't wrapped, this is one line for each cert:

```
[2020-0326-1003:11:10] : @{name=; Subject=CN=WinRM HTTPS mycomputer; Thumbprint=12345679679484747463etygvetevtreye; Issuer=CN=WinRM HTTPS computer; NotAfter=03/26/2023 09:38:09}
[2020-0326-1003:11:11] : @{name=; Subject=CN=mycompcert2.abc.de.fg; Thumbprint=fdhshs44he4hhh4the44h4h4; Issuer=CN=Enterprise CA, OU=Cert Svcs, O=A Corporation, L=location, S=state, C=AU; NotAfter=09/20/2050 10:30:00}
```

The only way I've found so far is to:

```
$allCerts | ForEach-Object {logger -logstr ($_ | Out-String)}
```

Which gives:

```
[2020-0326-0952:11:56] : 

name       :    
Subject    : CN=WinRM HTTPS mycomputer   
Thumbprint : 12345679679484747463etygvetevtreye   
Issuer     : CN=WinRM HTTPS computer  
NotAfter   : 03/26/2023 09:38:09




[2020-0326-0952:11:57] : 

name       :   
Subject    : CN=mycompcert2.abc.de.fg  
Thumbprint : fdhshs44he4hhh4the44h4h4  
CN=Enterprise CA, OU=Cert Svcs, O=A Corporation, L=location, S=state, C=AU  
NotAfter   : 09/20/2050 10:30:00
```

Is there a "tidier" way I can enumerate the properties of each member of the array to a single line in the log without having to use `| out-string`?

Comment: Not unless the default string representation works for you: `Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ |Foreach-Object { logger "$_" }`

Comment: The `logstr` parameter is converting the input to a string. You are sending it a custom object. You need to process it as an object instead of just converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `Logger` function seems to require a *string*. so you need to build the string 1st. the default `.ToString()` method will not give you what you want, tho.

you can do a slightly iffy trick and use `ConvertTo-CSV` to give you the lines that would be in a CSV file ... and skip the 1st line to get rid of the header line. something like the following ...

[my cert list for the machine has no certs, so i used the current user. also, i have no `Name` property ... only a `FriendlyName` property.]

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My |
    Select-Object -Property FriendlyName, Subject, Thumbprint, Issuer, NotAfter |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1
```

output ...

```
"APNS certificate";"CN=95F066ED-5A55-4053-84A0-D49E72C4AF6B";"42DA37600AFD9F0423FDCCF298A89C6CF1F945C8";"CN=Apple iPhone Device CA, OU=Apple iPhone, O=Apple Inc., C=US";"2016-11-03 2:18:59 PM"
"APNS certificate Direct";"CN=8E9D6C89-2BEF-4677-A9AD-84645ABFE44A";"2580F9FD8CB5E49EAC1035940D0D8EC09746A078";"CN=Apple iPhone Device CA, OU=Apple iPhone, O=Apple Inc., C=US";"2019-12-09 3:39:44 AM"
```

if you want to strip out the quotes, that seems fairly easy. [*grin*]